# How can I "display more" in a list?

Tags: mysql

like the next 15 values in the ITEMS table sorted by date added?

Comment: It depends on what your first query looks like. You'll probably need to show some more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to look at the `LIMIT` clause:

```
SELECT    *
FROM      items
ORDER BY  date_added DESC
LIMIT     0, 15;
```

Then to display the next 15 items, simply change the `0` of the `LIMIT` clause to `15`... then to `30`... then to `45`... and so on. This is called pagination.

Comment: makes sense in theory- but what would I use to actually allow users to keep changing that "starting point" woudl i build a new link that said "more" and change the code behind that... (does that make sense)

Comment: @adam: Yes, that's one way to tackle it. You simply need to keep track of what page the user is looking at, and if the user is in page 4, you should simply change the `LIMIT` to `60, 15`, to display the 15 rows from row `60` to row `74`. Otherwise, you may prefer to alter the last parameter of the `LIMIT` clause, such that you always return the full result set from the first row, to the row number you specify. For example `LIMIT 0, 45` will display the first 45 rows... `LIMIT 0, 60` the first 60 rows... and so on.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT column FROM table
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

http://www.petefreitag.com/item/451.cfm mentions `OFFSET` is supported by both PostgreSQL and MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

Before, you query

```
SELECT COUNT(foo) AS number_of_elements FROM table;
```

in order to know how many pages ( `CEIL(number_of_elements / elements_per_page)` ) you need.